# Enabling a button in WPF depending on ListBox.SelectedIndex

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a rather classic UI situation - two ListBoxes named `SelectedItems` and `AvailableItems` - the idea being that the items you have already selected live in `SelectedItems`, while the items that are available for adding to `SelectedItems` (i.e. every item that isn't already in there) live in `AvailableItems`.

Also, I have the `<` and `>` buttons to move the current selection from one list to the other (in addition to double clicking, which works fine).

Is it possible in WPF to set up a style/trigger to enable or disable the move buttons depending on anything being selected in either ListBox? `SelectedItems` is on the left side, so the `<` button will move the selected `AvailableItems` to that list. However, if no items are selected (`AvailableItems.SelectedIndex == -1`), I want this button to be disabled (`IsEnabled == false`) - and the other way around for the other list/button.

Is this possible to do directly in XAML, or do I need to create complex logic in the codebehind to handle it?

Comment: if by fun you mean utterly, utterly horrible, the-only-way-to-make-it-worse-would-be-with-regex, then yeah its great fun

Comment: @Will That's a good analogy because I would love to smash nuts with a rubber mallet

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here's your solution.

```
<Button Name="btn1" >click me    
    <Button.Style>        
        <Style>            
            <Style.Triggers>                
                <DataTrigger 
                     Binding ="{Binding ElementName=list1, Path=SelectedIndex}" 
                     Value="-1">                    
                    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="false"/>                    
                </DataTrigger>                
            </Style.Triggers>            
        </Style>        
    </Button.Style>    
</Button>
```

Answer (score 84):

Less code solution:

```
<Button Name="button1" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" />
```

If count is 0 that seems to map to false, > 0 to true.

Comment: the nice thing about the other answer is, you can use it for 2 lists, both have to have something selected to enable the button.

Comment: this is only if the listview has at least one items , the question is enable button when the item was selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Button IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ListName, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue=0}" >Remove</Button>
```

that worked in my case